# Change window icons of another PID

Tags: c, winapi

I made a firefox addon, a profile manager from which they can manage all their profiles. This addon allows multiple profiles. Profile is a group of windows of firefox with different PID.

On the profile I run this code from, the icon successfully changes. Is it possible to change the icon of another profile (if its running, if its not running its not an issue)?

I have the PID, i enumerated windows, and got a window handle. The ndo `SetClassLongPtr` on it but it doesnt seem to change or error.

This is the code I use to update the icon:

```
        var hIconBig_HANDLE = ostypes.API('LoadImage')(null, iconPath, ostypes.CONST.IMAGE_ICON, 256, 256, ostypes.CONST.LR_LOADFROMFILE); //todo: detect if winxp and if so then use 32 instead of 256 per https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f55b7ca0f89fe2610fa#file-_ff-addon-snippet-browseforbadgethencreatesaveanapply-js-L328
        var hIconSmall_HANDLE = ostypes.API('LoadImage')(null, iconPath, ostypes.CONST.IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, ostypes.CONST.LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        // LoadImage was returning null because i had declared LoadImageA but then i defeined LPCTSTR as ctypes.jschar. i had to use LoadImageW to use with ctypes.jschar. I didnt test but i guess to use with LoadImageA you have to use ctypes.char  


        var hIconBig_LONG_PTR = ctypes.cast(hIconBig_HANDLE, ostypes.IS64BIT ? ostypes.TYPE.LONG_PTR : ostypes.TYPE.LONG);
        var hIconSmall_LONG_PTR = ctypes.cast(hIconSmall_HANDLE, ostypes.IS64BIT ? ostypes.TYPE.LONG_PTR : ostypes.TYPE.LONG);

        var oldBigIcon = ostypes.API('SetClassLong')(cHwnd, ostypes.CONST.GCLP_HICON, hIconBig_LONG_PTR);
        var oldSmallIcon = ostypes.API('SetClassLong')(cHwnd, ostypes.CONST.GCLP_HICONSM, hIconSmall_LONG_PTR);
```

Thanks

## EDIT

Is it possible to use `SendMessage` to change the icon in same way as `SetClassLongPtr` does? That would be perfect! I strongly want to avoid `SendMessage` and `WM_SETICON` as that has some implications (please see comments below)

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would expect to be able to do this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wrote a profile manager, so people can edit names etc of profiles from this manager. Is this not possible?

Comment: You asked about the icons that the system shows. I don't see why you would expect to change the icon of some other process without their cooperation. An act that sounds hostile.

Comment: Thanks for super fast reply! I agree @DavidHeffernan my profile manager allows users to badge their icons, so it only changes with their direct consent, if i did illegal stuff Firefox wouldn't accept it on their store. If I don't allow badging icons user sees multiple of the exact same Firefox icon and they can't differentiate one profile from another. Image of succesful badging: http://i.imgur.com/UoAqCc8.png  The reason I have to change the icon instead of using image overlay is many I can get into that if you would like but its very much user friendly stuff with permission.

Comment: It's not *illegal* as in *there are laws preventing you from doing so*, it's *illegal* in that *for security reasons Windows doesn't let you mess around with windows/classes that you don't own*. There are a few other implications: the method you used to change the icon takes effect for all windows of that window class, so if that window class is registered globally then you'll affect every Firefox window; worse, however, is what happens if two Firefox instances running your plugin try to reset the icon twice? Both will have different `oldBigIcon`s so half the time you'll have the wrong icon...

Comment: Is there a reason you need to set the profile icon remotely like this? Wouldn't it be easier to use `WM_SETICON` or whatever the correct way to set a single window's icon is from within each profile? I imagine each profile is going to have your plugin, so...

Comment: Thanks @andlabs I can use `WM_SETICON` but it doesn't take affect on all windows, that's the reason I need `SetClassLong`. Is there by chance a way to use `SendMessage` to make it change the icon on the class as does `SetClassLong`? I have some other reasons to not use `SendMessage` and `WM_SETICON`, even though it works on `hWnd` of other PID, I can share those if you like. Ideally I need to use `SendMessage` to set the icon just like SetClassLong doe sit of class so it goes to all windows, is this possible?

Comment: Reason I'm shying away from `SendMessage` and `WM_SETICON` on the `hWnd`'s of the other PID, even though it works, is because (1) this method is used by many other addons, and I don't want to override their icons. The other thing is (2) I'll have to enumerate and get all windows then apply to all, which is just a minor reason. (3) If user uses profile manager from that profile, it will set with `SetClassLongPtr`, which will not have affect if `WM_SETICON` was done, and I'll have to do some more work to remove those `WM_SETICON` first, another minor reason but all the minor work adds up. haha

Comment: The other reason (4) is that if I do change all windows of that PID with `WM_SETICON` and `SendMessage` then I have to do some communication to tell it on next window open to remove the `WM_SETICON` and replace it with `SetClassLongPtr` so that future windows will also get the icon. __IN CONCLUSION:__ Even though `SendMessage` and `WM_SETICON` works its a last last resort. The biggest draw back is its overriding window icons I dont want to change, and the minor work here and there adds up to be a lot, but more work for me is just a minor reason.

Comment: The implications you mentioned I understand, and thankfully are not issues but strengths: (1) All windows take that icon, this is big strength/pro. (2) if two instances of my plugin try to update it twice its ok, as the icon is stored on disk, they will apply the same icon, so no issue there. Thanks very much for your thoughts on my subject!

Comment: For the global class thing, I meant all Firefox windows regardless of process. Of course, making sure the window class isn't registered globally (by looking at Firefox's source) would confirm this, and if it isn't, you wouldn't have a problem. For the icon changing thing, I meant in the code that changes the icon back to the old one (since you are saving the icon). I still don't understand why you aren't able to just have each profile instance manage its own icons, though.

Comment: Thanks @andlabs the biggest reason I can't make each profile manage its own icons is because my profile manager addon may not be installed in all profile.